# SQL Calendar PHP

Tags: php

I need help. In my database, I have a table of "Caledarios" where I have put each autonomous community of Spain, a table "Fechas" where I have the festive date and the community that belongs and a user table where each user has assigned a calendar, for example : user1 is assigned the Andalusian calendar. What does this mean, because the user has the holidays, the holidays of Andalusia. Well, the application collects the dates and you have to find out if there is a holiday between them. So far he does it very well. My problem is that only I only took the holidays of Andalusia for all the users because that is how I have the function:

```
function diashabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin){
$inicio = strtotime($fechainicio);
$final = strtotime($fechafin);

$dias = 0;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas WHERE fk_calendario = 1 AND FECHA_ZONA between '".$fechainicio."' AND '".$fechafin."'";
sc_lookup(rr, $sql);

while(date('Y-m-d', $inicio) <= date('Y-m-d', $final)){
$dias += date('N', $inicio) < 6 ? 1 : 0;
$inicio = strtotime("+1 day", $inicio);
}

$dias -= {rr[0][0]};

return $dias;
}
```

I want that for user2 that has Galicia calendar, take the holidays of Galicia, but I do not know how the sentence would go.

Some help??

Comment: Q: What is a BD?

Comment: @AndyG database but written in Spanish (BD = Base de datos)

Comment: Yes, BD is Database

Comment: what's `fk_calendario`? Is it set to 1 so the query gets the andalusian calendar or something completly different?

Comment: It is already modified

Comment: The "Fechas" table has a "fk_calendario" field that is a foreign key of "pk_calendario" of the "Calendarios" table

Comment: Well then just change the value of `fk_calendario` to the one that equeals to Galicia or what's that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am looking for is a SQL or PHP sentence user1 take the vacations of Andalucia and user2 take the vacations of Galicia, it depends on the user that has started the session

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't understand you in the first place. So relate your database tables and do a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas as f join calendarios as c on c.pk_calendario = f.fk_calendario join users as u on u.column_to_relate_to_calendarios = c.column_that_relates_to_users WHERE u.id_user = ? AND f.FECHA_ZONA between '".$fechainicio."' AND '".$fechafin."'`

Comment: column_to_relate_to_calendarios and column_that_relates_to_users?? I do not understand

Comment: Yes. You need a column in your table `users` that works like a foreign_key to calendarios so you can relate both tables. I used the ''column_to_relate_to_'' cause I don't know how your tables are made.

Comment: Many thanks! You have solved my doubt